# how to stop ini_set("max_execution_time", 0); at run time

Tags: php, mysql

I'am using `ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);` as upload file and insert data.

Now, due to the wrong file is uploaded, my loop is continuing inserting data in server table.
I have deleted the table then recreated it with the same name, loop insertion process is automatically processed.
How would I kill it?

```
"ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);" //process on Linux server.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep php // to get a list of php    processes

kill [process-id]
```

also

other way

If the command was executed as something like php /path/to/script.php, then you could do something like

```
pkill -f /path/to/script.php
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution and its is very simple. first i taken all back up from server side and mysql database.
then terminate my account (with that delete all data and process )and then recreate it account on server ....